# How to interpret the results of the Discrete Fourier Transform (FFT) in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft

There are many questions on this topic, and I have cycled through a lot of them getting conceptual pointers on handling frequencies ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/4089351) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17391353/4089351)), documentation on numpy functions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59979450/4089351)), how-to information on extracting magnitude and phase ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70760108/4089351)), and stepping outside the site, for example [this](https://erickson.academic.wlu.edu/files/courses2020/sigproc_s2020/readings/DFT_Intro.pdf) or [this](https://www.strollswithmydog.com/units-of-discrete-fourier-transform/#:%7E:text=The%20output%20of%20the%20DFT,the%20plot%20in%20Figure%202b.&text=So%20with%20typical%20setups%20the,%2Fset%20and%20cycles%2Fsample).

However, only the painful "proving it" to myself with simple examples and checking the output of different functions contrasted to their manual implementation has given me a bit of an idea.

The answer attempts to document and share details related to the DFT in Python that may constitute barriers of entry if not explained in simple terms.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

The DFT (FFT being its algorithmic computation) is a dot product between a finite discrete number of samples **N** of an analogue signal **s**(t) (a function of time or space) and a set of basis vectors of complex exponentials (sin and cos functions). Although the sample is naturally finite and may show no periodicity, it is implicitly thought of as a periodically repeating discrete function. Even when dealing with real-valued signals (the usual situation) it is convenient to work with complex numbers (Euler's equation). It may be intimidating to implement the function on a signal with `np.fft.fft(s)` only to get the output coefficients in complex numbers and get stuck in their interpretation. Some steps are essential:

###### What are the frequencies in the complex exponentials?

1. The DFT does not necessarily preserve the sampling frequency in Hertz. The frequencies are indices (**k**).
2. The indices **k** range from `0 to N - 1` and can be thought of as having units of **cycles / set** (the set being the `N` samples of the signal `s`). I will omit discussing the Nyquist limit, but for real signals the frequencies form a mirror image after **N / 2**, and given as negative decreasing values after that point (not a problem within the framework of implicit periodicity). The frequencies used in the FFT are not simply **k**, but **k / N**, thought of as having units of **cycles / sample**. See [this reference](https://www.strollswithmydog.com/units-of-discrete-fourier-transform/#:%7E:text=The%20output%20of%20the%20DFT,the%20plot%20in%20Figure%202b.&text=So%20with%20typical%20setups%20the,%2Fset%20and%20cycles%2Fsample). Example ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27191172/4089351)): If a signal is sampled `N = 5` times the frequencies are: `np.fft.fftfreq(5)`, yielding `[ 0 ,  0.2,  0.4, -0.4, -0.2]`, i.e. `[0/5, 1/5, 2/5, -2/5, -1/5]`.
3. To convert these frequencies to meaningful units (e.g. Hetz or mm) the values in cycles/sample above will need to be divided by sampling interval **T** (e.g. distance in seconds between samples). Continuing with the example above, there is a built-in call: `np.fft.fftfreq(5, d=T)`: If the analogue signal `s` is sampled `5` times at equidistant intervals `T = 1/2` sec for a total sample of `NT = 5 x 1/2 sec`, the normalized frequencies will be `np.fft.fftfreq(5, d = 1/2)`, yielding `[0 0.4 0.8 -0.8 -0.4]` or `[0/NT, 1/NT, 2/NT, -2/NT, -1/NT]`.
4. Either normalized or un-normalized frequencies are used to control **angular frequencies** (**ω_m**), expressed as **ω_m = 2π k/NT**. Note that `NT` is the total duration for
   which the signal was sampled. The index `k` does result in multiples of a fundamental frequency (**ω-naught**) corresponding to `k = 1` - the frequency of (co-)sine wave that completes
   exactly one oscillation over `NT` ([here](https://erickson.academic.wlu.edu/files/courses2020/sigproc_s2020/readings/DFT_Intro.pdf)).

### [image]

###### Magnitude, frequency and phase of the coefficients in the FFT

1. Given the output of the FFT `S = fft.fft(s)`, the **magnitude** of the output coefficients ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70760108/4089351)) is just the Euclidean norm of the complex numbers in the output coefficients adjusted for the symmetry in real signals (`x 2`) and for the number of samples `1/N`: `magnitudes = 1/N * np.abs(S)`
2. The frequencies are matched to the call explained above `np.fft.fftfreq(N)`, or more expediently to incorporate the actual analogue frequency units, `frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(N, d=T)`.
3. The phase of each coefficients is the angle of the complex number in polar form `phase = np.arctan(np.imag(S)/np.real(S))`

---

###### How to find the dominant frequencies in the signal s in the FFT and their coefficients?

1. Plotting aside, finding the index `k` corresponding the frequency with the highest magnitude can be accomplished as `index = np.argmax(np.abs(S))`. To find the `4` indices with the highest magnitude, for example, the call is `indices = np.argpartition(S,-4)[-4:]`.
2. And finding the actual corresponding coefficient: `S[index]` with frequency `freq_max = np.fft.fftfreq(N, d=T)[index]`.

---

###### Reproducing the original signal after obtaining the coefficients:

Reproducing `s` through sines and cosines (p.150 in [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/dsp-book/dsp_book_Ch8.pdf)):

```
    Re = np.real(S[index])
    Im = np.imag(S[index])
    
    s_recon = Re * 2/N * np.cos(-2 * np.pi * freq_max * t) + abs(Im) * 2/N * np.sin(-2 * np.pi * freq_max * t)
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10000           # Sample points     
T = 1/5000          # Spacing
# Total duration N * T= 2
t = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N, endpoint=False) # Time: Vector of 10,000 elements from 0 to N*T=2.
frequency = np.fft.fftfreq(t.size, d=T)      # Normalized Fourier frequencies in spectrum.

f0 = 25             # Frequency of the sampled wave
phi = np.pi/8       # Phase
A = 50              # Amplitude

s = A * np.cos(2 * np.pi * f0 * t + phi) # Signal

S = np.fft.fft(s)   # Unnormalized FFT

index = np.argmax(np.abs(S))
print(S[index])
magnitude = np.abs(S[index]) * 2/N
freq_max = frequency[index]

phase = np.arctan(np.imag(S[index])/np.real(S[index]))
print(f"magnitude: {magnitude}, freq_max: {freq_max}, phase: {phase}")
print(phi)

fig, [ax1,ax2] = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 5))
ax1.plot(t,s, linewidth=0.5, linestyle='-', color='r', marker='o', markersize=1,markerfacecolor=(1, 0, 0, 0.1))  
ax1.set_xlim([0, .31])
ax1.set_ylim([-51,51])
ax2.plot(frequency[0:N//2], 2/N * np.abs(S[0:N//2]), '.', color='xkcd:lightish blue', label='amplitude spectrum')
plt.xlim([0, 100])
plt.show()

Re = np.real(S[index])
Im = np.imag(S[index])

s_recon = Re*2/N * np.cos(-2 * np.pi * freq_max * t) + abs(Im)*2/N * np.sin(-2 * np.pi * freq_max * t)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 2.5))

plt.xlim(0,0.3)
plt.ylim(-51,51)
plt.plot(t,s_recon, linewidth=0.5, linestyle='-', color='r', marker='o', markersize=1,markerfacecolor=(1, 0, 0, 0.1))  
plt.show()

s.all() == s_recon.all()
```